# How does this example from the redux documentation work?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am reading the Redux documentation and it lists different ways of applying middleware that could work, but are not efficient before it gets to how Redux actually applies middleware.

I have no idea why this following method would work even though I see why it is not efficient:

```js
function applyMiddlewareByMonkeypatching(store, middlewares) {
  middlewares = middlewares.slice()
  middlewares.reverse()

  // Transform dispatch function with each middleware.
  middlewares.forEach(middleware =>
    store.dispatch = middleware(store)
  )
}

// We could use it to apply multiple middleware like this:

applyMiddlewareByMonkeypatching(store, [logger, crashReporter])
```

How could that possibly work? Wouldn't you just be overwriting the store.dispatch() function with every iteration of the forEach loop, and in the end all you would be applying is the last middleware in the array?

Here is a link to the documentation: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html

Answer (score 1):

After going through the docs, I believe I have an answer for you.

Let's take the logger function for example. Here it is below.

```
function logger(store) {
  let next = store.dispatch

  // Previously:
  // store.dispatch = function dispatchAndLog(action) {

  return function dispatchAndLog(action) {
    console.log('dispatching', action)
    let result = next(action)
    console.log('next state', store.getState())
    return result
  }
}
```

Here is the call to the logger function below

`store.dispatch = logger(store)`

So the `store` instance gets passed to `logger`. Once inside the `logger` function, the `next` variable holds the reference to the original `store.dispatch` function. Notice it has not been overwritten yet. Now, you dispatch the action using this line `next(action)` and store that in `result` and return the `result` value.

The whole reason you are overwriting the `store.dispatch` function is so that you don't have to make an explicit call to any middleware you are trying to apply.

From the docs

> Why do we even overwrite dispatch? Of course, to be able to call it
>   later, but there's also another reason: so that every middleware can
>   access (and call) the previously wrapped store.dispatch

Answer (score 0):

It is by the magic of closures.

Original Dispatch function in stored in next variable